# How to print a certain part of an Array?

Tags: java

i'm in need of assistance with a small error in my code. I have a program that has 4 `String` Arrays that i have to combine and print in separate places using constructors. I need to write a method: `Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search)` which searches for a string in the array and returns the matched `string` along with the other corresponding information.

For example:

`searchWithId(list, "P102432"); // search the list for the given id`

Output:

```
Searching for the id number:P102432 ...
Found the record for the id number:P102432

first name:Amber    Last Name:Nogofski
Id number:P102432
Employee number:No employee number has been assigned yet!
```

Heres my code so far:

Employee Class:

```
public static class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idNumber;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private int employeeCount;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param firstName first name
     * @param lastName last name
     * @param idNumber id number
     */
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String idNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        employeeCount = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Accessors here
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    // mutators here
    /**
     * @param firstName first name
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName last name
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param idNumber id number
     */
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param employeeNumber employee number
     */
    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "First name: " + getFirstName() + "\nLast name: " + getLastName()
                + "\nId number: " + getIdNumber() + "\nEmployee number: ";
        if (getEmployeeNumber() == null) {
            return result + "No employee number has been assigned yet!\n";
        }
        return result + getEmployeeNumber() + "\n";
    }

}
```

My main and other methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] firstNames = {"Fred", "John", "Amir", "James", "Bob", "Jay", "Amber"};
    String[] lastNames = {"Bond", "Kates", "Memar", "White", "Marley", "Brown", "Nogofski"};
    String[] idNumbers = {"R111111", "A222222", "AB11111", "KR22121", "V311133", "L242434", "P102432"};
    String[] employeeNum = {"1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555", "6666", "7777"};

    Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length];
    list = listOfEmployees(firstNames, lastNames, idNumbers); // create the list of employees in one array    
    System.out.println("List of employees before sorting...\n");
    printEmployeeList(list); //print the list of employees

    System.out.println(); // new line
    searchWithId(list, "P102432"); // search the list for the given id
    searchWithLastName(list, "Bond"); // search the list for the given last name

    System.out.println(); // new line
    searchWithId(list, "P1024444"); // search the list for the given id
    searchWithLastName(list, "BoNd"); // search the list for the given last name

    System.out.println();// new line
    sortWithFirstName(list); // sort the employee list and then call appropriate method to print it.
    list = assignEmployeeNum(list, employeeNum); // assign the employee number to the employees

    System.out.println("+++After adding the employee number to the list+++");// new line
    printEmployeeList(list); // print the list again with the employee number

    searchWithEmployeeNum(list, "5555"); // search the list for the given employee number 
    sortWithFirstName(list); // sort the employee list and then call appropriate method to print it.
}

public static Employee[] listOfEmployees(String[] firstName, String[] lastName, String[] idNumber) {
    Employee[] list = new Employee[firstName.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = new Employee(firstName[i], lastName[i], idNumber[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

public static void printEmployeeList(Employee[] list) {
    Arrays.stream(list).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            System.out.println("Found id number: " + search);
            //Arrays.toString(list); <- my try
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You want to print the whole array or the found number (which you already print)?

Comment: @krzyk just the found number

Comment: But you already do that: `System.out.println("Found id number: " + search);`

Comment: @krzyk the method `printEmployeeList` prints the whole array while the method `searchWithId` needs to only print the index.

Comment: Then just change to `System.out.println("Found id number: " + i);`.. it's not too difficult.

Comment: @krzyk thats just the first part check the output.

Comment: @developer033 that does not print the array though, that only prints a number (index)

Comment: Well, you said: "`searchWithId` needs to only print the index."

Comment: @developer033 was referring to the array index and its contents not just the index sorry.

Comment: @Deescomaster, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
   System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);            
   Employee[] filteredEmployees = new Employee[list.length];
   int index = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].getIdNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
         filteredEmployees[index++] = list[i];
      }
   }
   // It'll remove the null values:
   return Arrays.copyOfRange(filteredEmployees, 0, index);
}
```

### Java 8 Version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
   System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
   return Arrays.asList(list)
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.idNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(search))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new Employee[list.length]);
}
```

Comment: for some reason the first method wont work. it only shows `Searching for the id number` in the output.

Comment: How are you calling it? And which one are you using? The *first*?

Comment: calling it like this `searchWithId(list, "P1024444");`

Comment: and not the java 8 version just the first version you posted.

Comment: What happens? It doesn't printing nothing?

Comment: it prints `searching for the id number: P102432` and then `java result: 1`

Comment: @Deescomaster, I'm getting it: `Searching for the id number: P102432
[First name: Amber
Last name: Nogofski
Id number: P102432`. By the way you can't use ArrayList? If you don't use `ArrayList` you have to looping elements again to remove the *null* values... So, have you tested my edited version?

Comment: havent studied Arraylists in class yet so i cant use it. and still not getting the code for some reason. ive checked everything

Comment: So strange, can you make an edit showing where you're stucked?

Comment: @Deescomaster, check: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZUxfeXJ0X1JsSEU, it's working..

Comment: i think i found the problem. you modified the line: `Employee[] x = searchWithId(list, "P102432");` in the main method. also this line `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));`. however im not allowed to add anything to or change the main method.

Answer (score 0):

change your searchWithId method to mine:

first way is using `ArrayList` of `Employee`s

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    ArrayList<Employee> search_result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Employee employee : list) {
        if (employee.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            search_result.add(employee);
        }
    }
    return search_result.toArray(new Employee[search_result.size()]);
}
```

or you can use array of employee to do this

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    Employee search_result[] = new Employee[list.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (Employee employee : list) {
        if (employee.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            search_result[index] = employee;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(search_result, 0, index);
}
```

even you can use

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    Employee first_search_result[] = new Employee[list.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (Employee employee : list) {
        if (employee.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            first_search_result[index] = employee;
            index++;
        }
    }

    Employee final_search_result[] = new Employee[index];
    for (int i=0; i<first_search_result.length;i++) {
        if (first_search_result[i].getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            final_search_result[i] = first_search_result[i];
        }
    }

    return final_search_result;
}
```

and return `final_search_result`, to avoid using `Arrays.copyOfRange`

the above method in any way will return list of all employees with `search` id

Comment: great answer but is there a way to do this without the use of `ArrayList`? a little to advanced for me.

Comment: yes you can use array to do this. recheck my answer